# How updateEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I tried to update an fullcalendar event with updateEvent but only the first time works, the second time that I try to use this, it updates the first event too. Thanks and sorry for my english.

```
eventClick: function(event,element) {
    $('#ventanaEdit').removeClass('editarInv').addClass('editar');
    $('#titulo').val(event.title)
    $('#color').val(event.backgroundColor)
    $('#titulo').focus();

    $('#editar').click(function(){

    var titulo= document.getElementById('titulo').value;
    var color = document.form1[2].value;
    event.title= titulo;
    event.backgroundColor= color;
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);
    $('#formulario').each (function(){
              this.reset();
    });
    $('#ventanaEdit').removeClass('editar').addClass('editarInv');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding a new click event handler to #editar every time a click on an event on the calendar occurs. That way, previously edited events get updated too, when you click on #editar. You need to unbind the old event handler first:

```
// ...
$('#editar').unbind('click').click(function() {
// ...
```